# How to get the index number of a type from an Array type in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

consider the following typescript code:

```
type Data = [string, number, symbol]; // Array of types

// If I want to access 'symbol' I would do this:
type Value = Data[2]; //--> symbol

// I need to get the index of the 'symbol' which is 2

// How to create something like this:
type Index = GetIndex<Data, symbol>;
```

I want to know if there is a possibility to get the index of symbol type in the type 'Data'.

Comment: `Data.indexOf("symbol")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution returns the keys in string format (string `"2"` instead of number `2`).

Given an array `A` and a value type `T`, we use a mapped type to check which keys of `A` have values that match `T`.  If the type is correct, we return that key and otherwise we return `never`.  That gives us a mapped tuple `[never, never, "2"]` representing matching and non-matching keys.  We want just the values, not the tuple, so we add `[number]` at the end of our type which gives us the union of all elements in the tuple -- in this case it is just `"2"` as `never` is ignored here.

```
type GetIndex<A extends any[], T> = {
  [K in keyof A]:  A[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[number]

type Index = GetIndex<Data, symbol>; // Index is "2"
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/kNrR3N)

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks

Comment: is there a way to extract a literal number? like `2`

Answer (score 0):

Reply: is there a way to extract a literal number? like 2 – Eliav Louski

For transform to number you can use this utility type:

```
type ParseInt<T> = T extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never
```

Look to this question [string to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526617/typescript-is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-string-literal-type-to-a-number-type)

In this case it will look as:

```
type ParseInt<T> = T extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never
type GetIndex<A extends any[], T> = {
  [K in keyof A]:  A[K] extends T ? ParseInt<K> : never;
}[number]

type Index = GetIndex<Data, symbol>; // Index is 2 number
```