# TypeScript: is there a way to convert a string literal type to a number type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write a utility type `Number<T>` which accepts a string literal type that can be converted to a number, if not it returns a `never` type?

```
type Five = Number<'5'> // `Five` is of the type number 5
```

And I just wanted to preemptively answer the question about why I want to do this:

The reason I am asking this question is that I am trying to write an `Add` utility type which adds the number

```
type createArray<Len, Ele, Arr extends Ele[] = []> =  Arr['length'] extends Len ? Arr : createArray<Len, Ele, [Ele, ...Arr]>

type Add<A extends number, B extends number> = [...createArray<A, 1>, ...createArray<B, 1>]['length']
```

Right now it works

```js
type Answer = Add<3,10> // Answer is 13
```

But but it only accepts the `number` type. I wanted to make it also doesn't accept `string` type so that this also works `type Answer = Add<'3','10'>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to turn an arbitrary string literal type to a numeric literal type (I generally call this `StringToNumber<T>`).  There was a recent request at [microsoft/TypeScript#47141](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47141) asking for this, which was declined.  It's not something they care to support.  There is a still-open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) asking for support for arbitrary mathematics on literal types, which includes asking for `StringToNumber<T>`; maybe there's still some hope?  But I wouldn't count on it.

---

If all you care about is non-negative whole numbers less than about 1000 (due to restrictions in recursion even with [tail-call elimination](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types)) then you can implement it yourself with [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) manipulation, similar to how you're doing `Add`:

```
type StringToNumber<T extends string, A extends any[] = []> =
  T extends keyof [0, ...A] ? A['length'] : StringToNumber<T, [0, ...A]>
```

And you can see it work:

```
type Thirteen = StringToNumber<"13">;
// type Thirteen = 13
```

This is fragile in the same way as `Add`... if you pass unexpected things you might get slow compiler performance or errors:

```
// type Nope = Add<0.4, 10>
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
```

So you could try to limit inputs to valid numeric strings:

```
type Digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "";
type NonZero = Exclude<Digit, "0" | "">
type LessThanAThousand = "0" | `${NonZero}${Digit}${Digit}`

type StringToNumber<T extends LessThanAThousand, A extends any[] = []> =
  T extends LessThanAThousand ? T extends keyof [0, ...A] ?
  A['length'] : StringToNumber<T, [0, ...A]> : never;

type Oops = StringToNumber<"0.4"> // error
// ----------------------> ~~~~~
// Type '"0.4"' does not satisfy the constraint 'LessThanAThousand'.(2344)
```

So that works.

---

Still I don't know that I'd recommend anything like this unless there's a very good use case for it.  The `Add` utility type in and of itself isn't something the TS team thinks  it's worth supporting (which might be why ms/TS#47141 was declined).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAxgThAhsCBBOdEgDwBkIB2ANFAKIA2EJ6cUEAHigQCYDOZlA2gLpQC8UHgD5+UGpwDklAgHNgACwm8GTNlHwEoAfjEYoALlgJkaDFjyESFKoOskAdI5rchAKFehIY5s2yo6jIRqBACuALYARhBwJABCAarsoZHRIgKcjvbwSCg05qgkAIxCDo7ZJnk4sUVC3JLScorc7p7QqASsAO7Roqg+2ADMRQAMIgD0Y2Id3bQAluyFAy3g0AAiszKzwKIARMM7UAA+UDuFB8c7AEznJwM3OwAs9wCs9wBs9wDs9wAc9wCc9x2AG4PCsoAA5AD2BAAWtEoaJSPQYOQQswINh1ptgCQ9kC3K11BBWKwACryRAEVAUqEhVhU5i7fZHKAAAwAJABvaFwhEAX252K2gq5wuA-LZyy8AGVgHBZrIyVCIeEonBsGSEkF2PhSRSqTT5HSGSxqNqWOwqSAeKJhPxXFAoFqVDrifrKdTafTGdpnRa1ABrCAgKEAM0Ew1K9lQvC0jrE9UIjSUBigcoVSpVauimpInCjUEysZEhgIEAAbtFQWCvBTZnAUIRRBnFTJlaqUhrTnchKCJlAifXGxBmwJFtLoAB5KFgdgCVtZzvq7B7exPcaTaJwKFwVwDgC0R+PJ9PZ4PIgAftfr-vJmTwRI108JFBmFCSVACFDtgzgPMwxAQd5GgGAYVYeVEEVbYJD1clPSNE1GQkewAApLgGB4HgASiAA)

Comment: Hey thanks so much! do you happen to know how I can create a utility type `Minus` similar to `Add`? I have been trying to achieve that but couldn't figure out how you can do that.

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoJ49m) I guess? I feel kind of bad that this is just for a comment and that it doesn't go into a real answer anywhere; you might want to open a new question for it so I can write an actual answer. Or at least accept this one ‍♂️

Comment: wow I will definitely open a new question for it so I can learn how you managed to do it! This really blows my mind as I thought it was impossbile to implement `minus` since you can easily add more elements into an array but it seems no easy way to pop off elements from an array in TypeScript.

Comment: I opened a new question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536229/typescript-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-utility-type-to-do-minus-calculation-on-n

Answer (score 14):

TypeScript 4.8 will allow converting string literal types to other types like `number`, `bigint` or `boolean`. See this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094).

By creating a utlity type `ParseInt` we can *"cast"* a string literal to a `number` type.

```js
type ParseInt<T> = T extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never

type T0 = ParseInt<"1">    // 1
type T1 = ParseInt<"100">  // 100
type T2 = ParseInt<"-13">  // -13
type T3 = ParseInt<"abc">  // never
```

Here are examples for the other type conversions:

```
type ParseBigint<T> = T extends `${infer N extends bigint}` ? N : never

type T4 = ParseBigint<"1">    // 1n
type T5 = ParseBigint<"100">  // 100n
type T6 = ParseBigint<"abc">  // never


type ParseBoolean<T> = T extends `${infer N extends boolean}` ? N : never

type T7 = ParseBoolean<"true">   // true
type T8 = ParseBoolean<"false">  // false
type T9 = ParseBoolean<"abc">    // never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220618#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QJIDtgB4AqA+KAXihyggA9gJ0ATJKAAwBIBvAS3QDMIEoA5MpWp0o6AK4BbAEY8AvgygB+flABcoiADceAKB2hIJAAxFYiFBmwAiAIxWCURwHonUG-vDQcN0-GRpMLFsjI3tnVxsQj0McACZfcwDrAFobAGYwqBcoVLTorzSE-0sguCkAY0zs9C1dPQNoPxQAITYAcw5sfFNSCipaemZ2Lh4VPuF6KXbO+SUVdRrtBHrPEgAWIpbpwNtM8Ld0fJIAVk2IVo6dyNCHbOvDhpIANjOLztKKqtdFuqOm84A9gCADYQODoXAEYi9IQDRisDjcXgCcZwqRA0Hg2bKAQLWrLI44ADsrwxYIhVmACDEED22SpNMJAA5SSDyUFOHBgSgvlBOdyIISAJyszEUsqVBz7H4IIA)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Map manually like this:

```js
type MapStrNum = {
  "1": 1;
  "2": 2;
};
```

And then do this:

```js
type One = MapNumStr['1'] // One will be 1
```