# TypeScript: is there a way to create a utility type to do minus calculation on numbers?

Tags: typescript

I made a utility type to add two number type

```js
type createArray<Len, Ele, Arr extends Ele[] = []> =  Arr['length'] extends Len ? Arr : createArray<Len, Ele, [Ele, ...Arr]>

type Add<A extends number, B extends number> = [...createArray<A, 1>, ...createArray<B, 1>]['length']
```

so that `Add<1,2>` gives you `3` of the number type. However I was struggling to implement the `Minus` utility type to achieve the `minus` calculation

ideally `Minus<3,1>` would give you `2`.

Comment: A great post on this: https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f

Answer (score 5):

You can implement `Minus` in a similar way to how you implemented `Add`: by [variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) manipulation with your `CreateArray` type function:

```
type Minus<A extends number, B extends number> =
    CreateArray<A, 1> extends [...CreateArray<B, 1>, ...infer R] ? R['length'] : never;
```

Here we are creating two tuples of length `A` and `B`.  If `A` is greater than or equal to `B`, then `CreateArray<A, 1>` will start with at least the same elements from `CreateArray<B, 1>`.  By doing [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) on the rest of the elements from `CreateArray<A, 1>`, we get a tuple `R` whose length is `B` minus `A`:

```
type Seven = Minus<10, 3> // 7
type Two = Minus<3, 1> // 2
```

Please note that there are definitely caveats here, and they're the same as in `Add`; if your `A` or `B` are negative, or not whole numbers, or too large in magnitude (bigger than 999), you will run into compiler problems.  So be careful; this sort of code is for pleasure, not business.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCBBOdEgDwBkIB2ANFAKIA2EJ6cUEAHigQCYDOZlA2gLpQC8UHgD5+UGpwDklAgHNgACwm8GTNlHwEoAfjEYoALlgJkaDFjyESFKoOskAdI5rchAKFehIY5s2yo6jIRqBACuALYARhBwJABCAarsoZHRIgKcjvbwSCg05qgkAIxCDo7ZJnk4sUVC3JLScorc7p7QALIAlqGsfglBSeFRMVDxKv1QyUNprlCzRjmmmDgFUMV9LOwZZca5ZlU1pfZdAGbRUABKvDrn9YSNSgYTEABu0QDcLeDQACryHXAoQiiVA+bCFAAMJAAzCIAPSw1ZQjxfKAAZReQIEnW6YMhUBhUHhUAA7MivN8AO4Ae1E2JCPShNUJCIATO5XEA)