# Convert number literal type to string literal type

Tags: typescript

I've seen questions about converting string literal types to number types ([TypeScript: is there a way to convert a string literal type to a number type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526617/typescript-is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-string-literal-type-to-a-number-type)), but not the other way around. Is there a way to define a type `type NumberToString<N extends number>` such that e.g. `NumberToString<42>` is `42`?

The purpose of this is to provide a return type for `Object.keys` (in cases where I'm really, really sure that there are no extra properties).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much much much simpler now with template literal types:

```
type NumberToString<N extends number> = `${N}`;
```